# How to match pattern and their length on an array using regex

Tags: ruby

From the array `["EZY4567", "C038", "BA01618"]` I want to match pattern that starts with `[A-Z]` and has a length greater than 4 or length of 7 (any one would do). I tried with `scan` and `match` but they are throwing error.

```
["EZY4567", "C038", "BA01618"].each.scan(/^[A-Z].+{4,7}/) #=> undefined method scan
["EZY4567", "C038", "BA01618"].each.match(...) #=> undefined method
```

When I tried with Rubular, the pattern `^[A-Z](.){4,}` appeared to work. But this is not working in irb

```
 ["EZY4567", "C038", "BA01618"].to_s.scan(/^[A-Z](.){4,}/) #=> returns empty array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) should work:

```
["EZY4567", "C038", "BA01618"].grep /^[A-Z](.){4,}/
#=> ["EZY4567", "BA01618"]
```

Comment: It works great. So I tried this `[...].grep(/^[A-Z].+{0,4}/)` to capture `C038` but it is returning all elements. Whats wrong?

Comment: You have to append a `$`, e.g.: `/^[A-Z].{0,4}$/`

Comment: Brilliant. Just wondering why when I use this `/^[A-Z].+{0,4}$/` (note the `+`) I am getting all elements inspite of its `{min,max}`?

Comment: `.+` matches any character multiple times